# An easy supremum problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f$ be a positive decreasing function. What can we say about the following supremum.
$$
\sup_{t>1}\ln t\,f(t).
$$
More generally what can we say about the supremum of product of an increasing function and a decreasing function?

Comment: It can be any non-negative number (since you imposed $f>0$), for example take $f(t)=\frac{c}{\log t}$ with $c>0$ and you get $c$, if you take $\frac{1}{\log t}+1$ you get $+\infty$ and if you take $\frac{1}{t}$ you get $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inconclusive.

If $f(t) := 1/(\log\log t)$ for all suitable $t$, then $\log(t) f(t) \to \infty$; wheraes if $f(t) := 1/t$ for all suitable $t$, then $\log(t) f(t) \to 0$.
In both cases $f > 0$ eventually and is decreasing.